# TypeError: Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list' for two lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, typeerror

I have two lists:

```
xi_rppi = [[0.4404518],
 [0.35042380000000001,
  0.41857349999999999,
  0.087422100000000003,
  0.32525920000000003,
  0.31717889999999999,
  0.41572910000000002],
 [0.32572420000000002,
  0.2707909,
  0.37550240000000001,
  0.40988249999999998,
  0.36942079999999999,
  0.39833210000000002,
  0.34174739999999998]]

pi = [[1.0558920000000001],
 [1.0558920000000001,
  1.1739245,
  1.3051515,
  1.451047,
  1.613251,
  1.7935875000000001],
 [1.0558920000000001,
  1.1739245,
  1.3051515,
  1.451047,
  1.613251,
  1.7935875000000001,
  1.9940829999999998]]
```

When I want to multiply `xi_rppi[1]` with `pi[1]` for instance, I can do:

```
[a*b for a,b in zip(xi_rppi[1],pi[1])]
```

**But I want to multiply the entire list `xi_rppi` with `pi`.** When I try the above method, I can the error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try  the following code

```
print [[a*b for a,b in zip(xi_rppi[i],pi[i])] for i in range(len(xi_rppi))]
```

Comment: there you go, the nested output. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you want a flattened output or a nested output, but see if this makes sense -

```
print([ a*b for xi_rppi_instance,pi_instance in zip(xi_rppi,pi) for a,b in zip(xi_rppi_instance,pi_instance)])
```

It is a dual for loop problem, where I have used two `for` loops in list comprehension. Sample output would have helped!

Comment: I was going to give answer , just a bit late , bdw do you remember me :P

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul sure. hope you are doin' well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is two `for` loops:

```
result = [ [a*b  for a,b in zip(e1,e2) ] for e1,e2 in zip(xi_rppi,pi) ]
```

`result` will be:

```
[[0.46506953200560003],
 [0.3700096870296,
  0.49137368670075,
  0.11409908494815,
  0.4719663863824,
  0.5116891776039,
  0.7456465171462501],
 [0.34392957698640003,
  0.31788807188705004,
  0.4900875206136,
  0.5947587719774999,
  0.5959684750208,
  0.7144434754087501,
  0.6814726806341999]]
```

Answer (score 1):

> One line solution :

```
print([[sub_item[0] * sub_item[1] for sub_item in zip(item[0], item[1])] for item in zip(xi_rppi,pi)])
```

Output:

```
[[0.46506953200560003], [0.3700096870296, 0.49137368670075, 0.11409908494815, 0.4719663863824, 0.5116891776039, 0.7456465171462501], [0.34392957698640003, 0.31788807188705004, 0.4900875206136, 0.5947587719774999, 0.5959684750208, 0.7144434754087501, 0.6814726806341999]]
```

> Detailed Solution:

Above list comprehension is same as :

```
final=[]

for item in zip(xi_rppi,pi):
    semi_final=[]
    for sub_item in zip(item[0],item[1]):

        semi_final.append(sub_item[0]*sub_item[1])


    final.append(semi_final)
print(final)
```